# How to cite newspaper with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, newspaper

When I check my `bib` file, the newspaper article is included as `@misc` with all the information (I use Mendeley to build up my `bib` file). In the bibliography, however, the citation only includes author's and article's name (No newspaper name, month and day).

How should I include newspaper article in the `bib` file to cite it properly?

Comment: Have you considered using the `@article` entry type, with the `journal` field for the newspaper title, and `month` field for the day and month?

Comment: I thought about that, but is that the only option? I am afraid that it won't be consistently correct across bib style. I was hoping that there was a dedicated option for newspaper article (which does get cited differently from journal article in academic bibliography)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `@article` entry type is definitely the right one for citing newspaper articles.

As you can read in the `biblatex` manual:

> **article**
>
> An article in a journal, magazine, newspaper, or other periodical which forms
>   a self-contained unit with its own title. The title of the periodical is given in
>   the `journaltitle` field. If the issue has its own title in addition to the main
>   title of the periodical, it goes in the `issuetitle` field. Note that `editor` and
>   related fields refer to the journal while `translator` and related fields refer
>   to the article.
>
> Required fields: `author`, `title`, `journaltitle`, `year`/`date`
>
> Optional fields: `translator`, `annotator`, `commentator`, `subtitle`,
>   `titleaddon` , `editor` , `editora` , `editorb` , `editorc` , `journalsubtitle` ,
>   `issuetitle`, `issuesubtitle`, `language`, `origlanguage`, `series`,
>   `volume`, `number`, `eid`, `issue`, `month`, `pages`, `version`, `note`, `issn`,
>   `addendum`, `pubstate`, `doi`, `eprint`, `eprintclass`, `eprinttype`, `url`,
>   `urldate`

Fields can be different if you don't use `biblatex`, but the concept is the same.