# Bibtex day and Month Problem

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, apacite

I have a problem with Bibtex and its `day` and `month` entries.

Judging from my Google search a lot of people want to suppress these entries - I however want to actually see them in my output.

This is what I use:

```
@ARTICLE{Jurgensen,
  author = {J{\"u}rgensen, Nadine},
  title = {{Die Geb{\"u}hren geh{\"o}ren abgeschafft}},
  journal = {Neue Z{\"u}rcher Zeitung},
  year = {2012},
  month = {Jul},
  day = {19},
  pages = {11},
}
```

And this my output:

[image]

What I want to see in the end is something along these lines:
[image]

For completeness, here my (shortened) MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib,setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{times} 
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\bibliography{sqwg2}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me please find the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I rewrote the answer more or less completely after the OP provided an important piece of information, *viz.*, that the bibliographic items of his/her document must be formatted according to APA guidelines.)

If your bibliography has to be formatted according to current APA guidelines, you should be using the `apacite` bibliography style, along with the `apacite` citation management package. FWIW, the `apalike` bibliography style is ca 30 years old and, as such, does not implement *current* APA formatting guidelines...

The good news is that the `apacite` style -- unlike the `apalike` style -- knows what to do with fields named `day` and `month` and recognizes an entry type called `@newspaper`. All you really need to do, mainly, is to change the entry type from `@article` to `@newspaper`. If you want to use natbib-like citation commands, you should load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`.

Incidentally, if you change the argument of the `month` field from `{July}` to `jul` (note: no curly braces), you'll get the language-appropriate form of the month and day fields ("July 19", "19. Juli", "19 juillet", etc) automatically if the `babel` package is loaded with a suitable language option. Thus, do make a habit of using only `jan`, `feb`, `mar`, etc as the arguments of the `month` field.

---

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sqwg2.bib}
@newspaper{Jurgensen,
  author  = {J{\"u}rgensen, Nadine},
  title   = {{Die Geb{\"u}hren geh{\"o}ren abgeschafft}},
  journal = {Neue Z{\"u}rcher Zeitung},
  year    = {2012},
  month   = jul,
  day     = {19},
  pages   = {11},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citep{Jurgensen}
\bibliography{sqwg2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mico - I use `apalike` because I thought this will ensure that all citazions are in apa-style and, on top of that, citations are not recognized if I remove it.  I chose `@article` because of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119899/how-to-cite-newspaper-with-natbib).   I like your solution, but I would prefer to really have the date as one, i.e. (2012, July 19) and right behind the author's name. Is that possible?

Comment: @Daniel - Did you try changing the `year` field to `{2012, July 19}` and the `note` field to `p.~19`? (Be sure to re-run BibTeX and LaTeX after changing a bib entry.)

Comment: If I do this, then everything looks as I want in the bibliography, but the `\citep` commands shows "(Jürgensen, y 19)" and not "(Jürgensen, 2012)".

Comment: Another insecurity regarding the first part of your answer: Is the `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` and `\begin{filecontents}{sqwg2.bib}` to be put in the .bib file or my actual latex? If I try to copy it into my latex file, it causes errors.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for indicating that your bibliography has to conform to (current?) APA formatting guidelines. I've rewritten my answer significantly as a result. BTW, the `filecontents` package is needed to make my answer code self-contained. You should be editing your real bib file separately, i.e., not as a "prefix" to the main tex file.

Comment: @Daniel - Which TeX distribution do you use?